# Nullable date in Freemarker

Tags: java, freemarker

This is a piece of my freemarker template:

```
${order.needByDate?if_exists?date}
```

I want it to work as following:

- if `needByDate` is null, then write nothing
- if it is not null, then write the date part

The above works only in second scenario. What is the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a smarter way of doing this but the following should do the job.

```
<#if order.needByDate??>${order.needByDate?date}</#if>
```

Answer (score 19):

This should also work

```
${(order.needByDate?date)!}
```

The parentheses are necessary

You can also add a default value such as "n/a" like this

```
${(order.needByDate?date)!"n/a"}
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution that considers null and empty-string values:

For [Freemarker version 2.3.23 or newer](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_boolean.html#ref_builtin_then):

```
${aDateField?has_content?then(aDateField?datetime?string["MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"],"")}
```

For older versions:

```
<#if aDateField?has_content>
${aDateField?datetime?string["MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"]}
</#if>
```

You can test it at https://try.freemarker.apache.org/

Comment: It works well!!